# Accessing spring.net propery directlly not via object

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, spring.net

I know spring.net configures classes to Spring objects. Instances of those classes are returned by Spring.NET framework via getters. I am asked to access spring.net Object property only (that is directly from inside the class using C# property). Is that possible in the first place, if yes how can I do it?

```
class Student
{
    public string firstName{get;set};
    public string lastName{get;set}
}

<object id="MySudent" Type="StudenntsProject.Student,StudentProject">
    <property name="firstName" value="David">
    <property name="lastName"  value="Fletcher">
</object>

class NewStudent
{
     public NewStudent()
     {
           if( Student.firstName == null)
           throw new Exception;
     }

     if(Student
     // I have added this property. Lets say the value of this property is
     // hardcoded and is not need in the class. Can I use this method directly
     // in the class. I know I have to add reference to in the xml but how 
     // will it work and is it even possible to do that?
     property IsOutofState{get;set}

     //This fetches the object
     property Student Student{get;set}
}
```

I know my example is quite lame but want to an idea if I can read spring property directly in C# code (not via objects)

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the relation between the `NewStudent` and the `Student` classes? Could you code up a minimal working (compiling & working spring configuration) and then rephrase your question? Then we can better help you.

Comment: @Marijn sorry with this pathetic example :) Basically I want to access Spring.NET property from the code without using the container object itself. It is now working for me but has some issues. I do not understand how it works though.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "access spring.net property from the code"? I'm missing something here. Could you show us the code that works for you?

Comment: So I have a spring `<object name=student>` and lets say it has a property,`Name`. I want to access this property in the code using a property (not an object). I know Spring returns instance of an object for us. But want to access this property in code like `if (Name="Jay")..` In this case Name is the property inside the class where I am using it and it is mapped to the Name property of Student object.

Comment: You're right that you don't want to use the spring.net container everywhere; typically you only used in a single place in your application (the composition root). But it's still not really clear to me how you are using / want to use the spring.net container.